# Michael Hunger Batch Importer: Having trouble importing nodes and relationships into the neo4j database

Tags: java, shell, neo4j, data-importer

I'm having trouble importing `nodes` and `relationships`.
I'm trying to follow the instructions on: [batch-importer](http://maxdemarzi.com/2012/02/28/batch-importer-part-1/#comment-1807),
I have also downloaded the import zip file from : [batch-import github](https://github.com/jexp/batch-import).

I have built the project successfully using `maven` and created the `nodes` and `relationships` `csv` files.
HOWEVER, I did this differently as the given command prompt commands gave me errors.  Instead, I imported the project as an existing maven project and ran the `TestDataGenerator.java` file on `eclipse`. I know this worked because the `csv` files were created.

I tried the command prompt file to execute the import but it did not work as seen in the picture.

Can you please help me?? Please give me step by step instruction as I am a newbie to command prompt and maven.

Also I'm unable to post images but here's a description of my error message:

```
"Exception in thread main" org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.CommonAbstractStore.close<CommonAbstractStore.java:618> ...
```

Comment: Can you please post the errors you got by compiling it using the command line.